# how to make footer <div> as relative to zoom-able content <div>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, zooming

I am doing simple zooming  implementation, that is working fine but the problem is when i do zoom-in. the footer div locating in the same place and there is lot of white space appearing between zooming div and footer.

Please help me how to maintain same gap between zoom-able div and footer even you did zoom-in/zoom-out.

I tried all the postion options even it not  happening as expected please need help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0033)http://3dant.com/apps/graphpaper/ -->
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    function dragStart(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.getAttribute('id'));
        ev.dataTransfer.setDragImage(ev.target, 0, 0);
        return true;
    }
    function dragEnter(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        return true;
    }
    function dragOver(ev) {
        return false;
    }
    function dragDrop(ev) {
        var src = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(src));
        ev.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }

    // Zooming
    var sclVal = 1;
    var minZoom = 0.5;
    var maxZoom = 1.5;

    function ZoomIn(event) {
        if (sclVal > minZoom ) {
            sclVal = sclVal - 0.1;
            console.log(sclVal);
            if (sclVal > minZoom && sclVal < maxZoom) {
                $("#section").css("-ms-transform", "scale(" + sclVal + ")");
                $("#section").css("-webkit-transform", "scale(" + sclVal + ")");
                $("#section").css("transform", "scale(" + sclVal + ")");
            }
        }
    };

    function ZoomOut(event) {
        if (sclVal < maxZoom ) {
            sclVal = sclVal + 0.1;
            console.log(sclVal);
            if (sclVal > minZoom && sclVal < maxZoom) {
                $("#section").css("-ms-transform", "scale(" + sclVal + ")");
                $("#section").css("-webkit-transform", "scale(" + sclVal + ")");
                $("#section").css("transform", "scale(" + sclVal + ")");
            }
        }
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#ZoomOut").click(function(event) {
            ZoomOut();

        });


        $("#ZoomIn").click(function(event) {
            ZoomIn();

        });


    });

</script>
<style>

#graph_paper {
    border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
    height: 700px;
    width: 1340px;
}

#header {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}

#nav {
    line-height: 30px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    height: 700px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
}

#section {
    width: 350px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    transform-origin: top left;
}

#footer {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    left:10px;
}

#cellDiv2 {
    height: 500px;
    width: 350px;
    border: 1px #D3D3D3 solid;
}

td,table {
    border: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="header">
        <h1>Id Card Print</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="nav">

            <table id="table1" draggable="true" ondragstart="return dragStart(event)">
                <tr>
                    <td>aaaaaaaaaa</td>
                    <td>bbbbbbbbbb</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>cccccccccc</td>
                    <td>dddddddddd</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        <input id="ZoomIn" type="button" value="-" />
        <input id="ZoomOut" type="button" value="+" />
    </div>
    <div id="section">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="cellDiv2" ondragenter="return dragEnter(event)"
                        ondrop="return dragDrop(event)"
                        ondragover="return dragOver(event)"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="cellDiv2" ondragenter="return dragEnter(event)"
                        ondrop="return dragDrop(event)"
                        ondragover="return dragOver(event)"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="cellDiv2" ondragenter="return dragEnter(event)"
                        ondrop="return dragDrop(event)"
                        ondragover="return dragOver(event)"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="cellDiv2" ondragenter="return dragEnter(event)"
                        ondrop="return dragDrop(event)"
                        ondragover="return dragOver(event)"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="cellDiv2" ondragenter="return dragEnter(event)"
                        ondrop="return dragDrop(event)"
                        ondragover="return dragOver(event)"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="cellDiv2" ondragenter="return dragEnter(event)"
                        ondrop="return dragDrop(event)"
                        ondragover="return dragOver(event)"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="cellDiv2" ondragenter="return dragEnter(event)"
                        ondrop="return dragDrop(event)"
                        ondragover="return dragOver(event)"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="cellDiv2" ondragenter="return dragEnter(event)"
                        ondrop="return dragDrop(event)"
                        ondragover="return dragOver(event)"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="cellDiv2" ondragenter="return dragEnter(event)"
                        ondrop="return dragDrop(event)"
                        ondragover="return dragOver(event)"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>

    <div id="footer">Copyright ..............</div>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ravikumarmaddi/z16jc6wa/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that transforming a div will not change its height.

By modifying the coordinate space, CSS transforms change the position and shape of the affected content without disrupting the normal document flow. This guide provides an introduction to using transforms. [mdn link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transforms)

One solution is to set the bottom margin on ZoomIn and Zoom Out as

```
$("#section").css("margin-bottom", '-' + parseInt((1-sclVal)*$("#section").height()) + 'px');
```

try http://jsfiddle.net/z16jc6wa/2/

Comment: thanks for your answer, But it not working in chrome.My mean, footer is relative to content, but it is showing white space after footer div in Chrome. It is good in Firefox.